# How to calculate "1+1" without using eval(parse(...?

Tags: r, eval

I have been looking for quite a while but it seems the answer always seems to be to use `eval(parse(text="1+1"))`.

I have a column in my data frame, it has a list of strings such as "1+1*6", "1*4/3" etc. I wish to compute these into a new column without using the `eval(parse(` functions as I am looking to do it over 8 million rows.

It is basically an attempt to answer the question: Given the numbers `1:9` find all the solutions where `(A_B_C) / (D_E_F) = GHI`, where `A:I` are the numbers `1:9` (without repeating) and the underscores are one of the four operators `*, /, +,-`, also without repeating.

I created a dataframe with all the permutations of `1:9` and for each of these I calculated the permutations of the four operators.

```
require(gtools)
x <- permutations(n = 9, r = 9, v = 1:9)
y <- permutations(n = 4, r = 4, v = c("*", "/", "+", "-"))

for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(y)){
    math <- paste("(", x[i,1], y[j,1], x[i,2],y[j,2], x[i,3],")", "/", "(", x[i,4] ,y[j,3], x[i,5] ,y[j,4], x[i,6],")")
    equals <- eval(parse(text=math))
    sum <- as.numeric(paste0(x[i,7], x[i,8], x[i,9]))
    if(sum==equals) {
       print(c(i,j))
    }
  }
}
```

However this takes far too long, hence I am trying to remove the time consuming `eval(parse(..`

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Freddie

Comment: Please update your question and make it easier to read.

Comment: Keep all numbers in 9 column, then play with something like this "+(2, 3)". Can't format properly, wrap the + sign with backtics.

Comment: I agree with @zx8754, you are basically deparsing when you construct your strings. Avoid that and there is no need to parse. If you want more help, you should create a smaller example. Running your code takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorisation is key

```
math <- apply(
  y,
  1,
  function(j){
    paste("(", x[, 1], j[1], x[, 2], j[2], x[, 3],")/(", x[, 4], j[3], x[, 5], j[4], x[, 6], ")")
  }
)
math <- apply(math, 2, paste, collapse = ",")
math <- paste("c(", math, ")")
equals <- sapply(parse(text = math), eval)
sum <-matrix(x[, 7] * 100 + x[, 8] * 10 + x[, 9], nrow = nrow(x), ncol = nrow(y))
abs(sum - equals) < 1e-8
```

Let's see what the difference in speed is

require(gtools)
    x <- permutations(n = 9, r = 9, v = 1:9)
    y <- permutations(n = 4, r = 4, v = c("*", "/", "+", "-"))

```
x <- x[sample(nrow(x), 40), ]
y <- y[sample(nrow(y), 20), ]

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  loop = for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(y)){
      math <- paste("(", x[i,1], y[j,1], x[i,2],y[j,2], x[i,3],")", "/", "(", x[i,4] ,y[j,3], x[i,5] ,y[j,4], x[i,6],")")
      equals <- eval(parse(text=math))
      sum <- as.numeric(paste0(x[i,7], x[i,8], x[i,9]))
      if(sum==equals) {
         print(c(i,j))
      }
    }
  },
  vectorised = {
    math <- apply(
      y,
      1,
      function(j){
        paste("(", x[, 1], j[1], x[, 2], j[2], x[, 3],")/(", x[, 4], j[3], x[, 5], j[4], x[, 6], ")")
      }
    )
    math <- apply(math, 2, paste, collapse = ",")
    math <- paste("c(", math, ")")
    equals <- sapply(parse(text = math), eval)
    sum <-matrix(x[, 7] * 100 + x[, 8] * 10 + x[, 9], nrow = nrow(x), ncol = nrow(y))
    abs(sum - equals) < 1e-8
  }
)
```

The results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
       loop 158.666383 162.084918 167.477490 165.880665 170.258076 240.43746   100   b
 vectorised   8.540623   8.966214   9.613615   9.142515   9.413117  17.88282   100  a
```

Comment: Hi Thierry, Thanks for you comment. I tried running your vectorized code `equals <- sapply(parse(text = math), eval)` but i got the error `Error in parse(text = math) : negative length vectors are not allowed` - not entirely sure why. Thanks!